# Workaround to downloading and importing module in Spyder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odbc, anaconda, spyder

I am new to Python and I have downloaded Anaconda and use Spyder.  Is there a way to find a workaround to import an external module, specifically I am trying to import pyodbc?

code.google.com/p/pyodbc/

Since I'm using spyder, I cannot import this module through the setup.py file.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Anaconda, you can just type this in a terminal (`cmd.exe` in Windows) to install `pyodbc`

```
conda install pyodbc
```

Then you could call it and use it from Spyder.